# GCP API dashboard does not count all my requests

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-console

I have an app running on the appengine that uses Cloud DataStore and Cloud Storage. I know for sure DataStore and Storage are used since there's code for that and if I disable the APIs, the app stops working.

[image: screenshot]

But whatever I do, I can't see the DataStore/Storage requests in the API dashboard. Is that expected ? Is there sampling or anything like that ?

Comment: Did you check if you are seeing for the right project? I noticed some delay in those metrics, but is not more than an hour or so.

Comment: Yep, definitely the right project. Maybe it's just lag but even if I set a 30 days period, there's no activity which seems pretty weird...

Comment: Well, I did some digging, maybe it's because you are still on the free quota for those services.

Comment: I am definitely still on the free quota. It still feels weird that some APIs get counted (appengine) but not others (datastore). It would be nice to have requests monitoring for all requests